# If in a metric space X, the only dense set is X, what can we say about the metric structure or topology?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If in a metric space X, the only dense set is X, what can we say about the metric structure or topology?

For the easy case, if X is finite, then every singleton is open so the dense set equals X. If X is infinite and the only dense set is X, then would that imply X and the empty set are the only open sets?

Comment: It implies that every point is isolated hence the space is discrete

Comment: Even with an infinite set, you can have the discrete metric which would render only $X$ to be a dense set. However, here as well all the subsets are open. Also, do you think that a topological space with only $X$ and $\emptyset$ open can be a metric space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. Then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not dense; in other words, $\overline{X\setminus\{x\}}=X\setminus\{x\}$. So, $X\setminus\{x\}$ is closed, and therefore $\{x\}$ is open. Therefore, the topology of $X$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: this is a very neat proof. thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Alessandro's comment, I give a proof.

Let $X$ be a metric space where the only dense set is $X$ itself. Then, for any $x \in X$, the set $X \setminus \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$ is not dense. That means, there is a point $y \in X$ which is not a limit point of $X \setminus \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$. Since the set contains every other point, except $x$, we must have $y = x$. That is, $x$ is not a limit point of $X \setminus \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$. Hence, there is an open set $O$ such that $x \in O$ and $O \cap X \setminus \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace = \emptyset$. This forces us to conclude that $O = \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$.

Since singleton sets are open, the space is discrete.

Comment: The proof is actually much simpler. If $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not dense then its closure must be itself (cannot be $X$) Thus $X\setminus\{x\}$ is closed, i.e.$\{x\}$ is open.

Comment: That is also true! This is another way, though, which came to my mind the first time I read the question.